# Calling a function in a php select statement

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to order my results according to distances in ascending order. I there created php function to calculate the distances and return the value. When i test the function in isolation it works, but when i try to call it in a php select statement it does not work. Where might i be going wrong. Below is the code snippet.

```
<?php
include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();

function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) *         cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  return ($miles * 1.609344); 
}

$sql = 'SELECT weather_locations.location_id, weather_locations.location_name,
distance(weather_locations.latitude, weather_locations.longtitude, -20.132507, 28.626479) AS mydistance,
...
...
ORDER BY mydistance'
```

Those hard coded values are just to test. Otherwise i will retrieve the real values from the user

Answer (score 1):

Use proper concatenation

```
$sql = 'SELECT weather_locations.location_id, weather_locations.location_name,'.distance(weather_locations.latitude, weather_locations.longtitude, -20.132507, 28.626479).' AS mydistance ...
```

**Explanation :**

in your Code , your function is considered as Plain string.So you need to tell php that `hey PHP, this is function, not a string`. So to separate function from rest of the string make 3 parts of query here.

1. String part 1 (before function).
2. returned value (the function).
3. String part 3 (after function).

And concate them all.

**Edit 2 : More explanation:**

part 1 :

```
'SELECT weather_locations.location_id, weather_locations.location_name,'
```

part 2 :

```
 distance(weather_locations.latitude, weather_locations.longtitude, -20.132507, 28.626479)
```

part 3 :

```
' AS mydistance, ...'
```

**Your code has error so your final** query would come up like(which was your wrong code) :

```
'SELECT weather_locations.location_id,weather_locations.location_name,distance() AS mydistance ...'
```

Where do you see result of your function ?? It is treated as string , so function will not be executed in your code.

So  My final **Proper Query** built will result like this ->

```
'SELECT weather_locations.location_id,weather_locations.location_name,Your result Of Function named as Distance() AS mydistance ...'
```

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Well the truth is i really dont understand what you are suggesting. I have tried to think it through but im just coming up blank

Comment: @HopewellMutanda , and one more longitude and lattitude should be php variable like $langitude, $lattitude which is not a part of question. I answered what you were missing in concatenation.

Comment: let me try to implement it

Comment: @HopewellMutanda sure , firstly after implementing , print query like `echo $sql ;` first to check what query is building.

Comment: And according to me you also have syntax error while **Calling** function. Use `$` before variable name.  So final string will be `distance($weather_locations.latitude, $weather_locations.longtitude, -20.132507, 28.626479)`

Answer (score 0):

Store the distance first and then insert it to the query.

```
$distance = distance($weather_locations.latitude, $weather_locations.longtitude, -20.132507, 28.626479);
$sql = 'SELECT weather_locations.location_id, weather_locations.location_name, '.
$distance.' AS mydistance, ...'
```

Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) on how to cancat string in php.

*Update*

Based on your comment I see you misunderstand some things.
You need to first get the values and then query the db.

```
    $latitude_query = "SELECT latitude ..."
    $longtitude_query = "SELECT longtitude ..."
    $latitude = $latitude_query->fetch();
    $longtitude = $longtitude_query->fetch();
    $distance = distance($latitude, $longtitude, -20.132507, 28.626479);

    $sql = 'SELECT weather_locations.location_id, weather_locations.location_name,
    '.$distance.' AS mydistance, ...'
```

Comment: Yes i know how to concatinate but my question is weather_locations.latitude and weather_locations.longtitude should be retrieved from the database. How im i supposed to use them out of the select statement because that will definately through an error

Comment: You need to retrieve the values first!! You can not assume that those variables will be replaced with the need values by mysql itself. If you want you need to write the `distance` method as stored procedure inside mysql.